# External Content Libraries not resolving images

Tags: core-service, ecl

I am trying to test accessing images directly into Tridion from an external source, so I am trying to get ECL's working on my dev server but have hit an issue.  As a test I am using the Flickr ECL from the Tridion site.

Everything works well.  The stub area is created and I can see images in the Flickr area.  It is all good until I publish the page.

The component is effectively an article with header and a RTF for paragraphs.

If I use a Hyperlink and specify Component and pick the image from the ECL within the RTF, it resolves it, so when I click the link, it shows me the picture.

If I use the Image button and select from the ECL within the RTF, it does not resolve and leaves it as a `.ecl` extension.

Tridion Support have stated that the code (`<a>` tag and `<img>` tag) are correct, but cannot explain why not getting resolved in both cases.

I am using the standard Get and Resolve TBB's that came with the install.

The image source is having `/media/images/` added to the front of the `.ecl` link.  This means to me that it thinks it is an image and not an ECL.  I have placed the **Get** / **Resolve** TBB before and after the **Default Finish Actions** in my Component Template to no avail.

I have tried to implement the **ECL Template Building Block** that is on the Tridion site but don't fully understand how to get it installed into Tridion once built.  This is an area I am currently lacking knowledge.

Does anyone have anything that might help me?

Thanks.

Comment: what version of SDL Tridion are you talking about?

Comment: Apologies, 2013 standard version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to 2013 SP1 HR1, you will get a **Resolve ECL Items** TBB, which is way better than the two TBBs there were on 2013 GA (and GA is not supported anymore anyways).

The **Resolve ECL Items** TBB in 2013 SP1 HR1, is identical to the one I have on GitHub https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/wiki/EclTbb (and https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/tree/master/ECL%20TBB/trunk).

If you build your own TBB, you need to upload the assembly into Tridion. You can use the `TcmUploadAssembly.exe` tool for that, or just create a TBB in Tridion and change it to an Assembly TBB and upload the assembly via the UI.

I think the issue you see is because of the TBBs you are now using, but I might be missing some information, let us know if this helps any.

Comment: Thanks.  I had a feeling that this would be the case.  I will try to implement the ECL TBB next week.  I tried to use TcmUploadAssembly.exe command from the post-build but I did not have a C:\Tridion\bin\client\config.xml file and could not work out what to put in it.

Comment: @StevenFisher did you check the documentation? http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-6F1D382A-84C0-49E9-8849-C54E876759B9

Comment: Yes, I saw it but I did not know what to do as the only mention of config.xml is "where config.xml is the name of the configuration file you wish to create or update".  No explaination of what should be in it.

Comment: @StevenFisher so run the command to create the file as it states there, it will fill it based on the info you give.

Comment: I found an article on what needed to be in the file.  Now all uploaded and working.  Interestingly your TBB fixed the <img> issue but still needed the original versions (Get and Resolve) to do <a> tags.